# DefaultDict behaves differently in both cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, defaultdict

I have the following :

```
a = [{ "_id" : { "reportId" : "5a27cda63fff647c33a14b31" }, "amount" : 3000 },
     { "_id" : { "reportId" : "5a27cda63fff647c33a14b31", "name" : "sriram sathyan" }, "amount" : 0 },
     { "_id" : { "reportId" : "5a27cf173f978655f2efbee7" }, "amount" : 1200 },
     { "_id" : { "reportId" : "5a27cf173f978655f2efbee7", "name" : "karthik subbaraj" }, "amount" : 0 }
    ]
```

I wanted the following structure:

```
{'reportid1':{'name':'sriram sathyan','amount':3000}, .....}
```

I tried the followig code:

```
names = defaultdict(dict)
for item in a:
   report_id = item['_id']['reportId']
   amount = item['amount']
   names[report_id] = {'name': item['_id'].get('name','')}
   if amount != 0:
      names[report_id].update({'amount': amount})
print(dict(names))
```

Outputs :

```
{'5a27cda63fff647c33a14b31': {'name': 'sriram sathyan'}, '5a27cf173f978655f2efbee7': {'name': 'karthik subbaraj'}}
```

( not what i wanted)

I then changed the above code to:

```
for item in a:
    report_id = item['_id']['reportId']
    amount = item['amount']
    if amount != 0:
        names[report_id] = {'amount': amount}
    names[report_id].update({'name': item['_id'].get('name','')})
print(dict(names))
```

This outputs:

```
{'5a27cda63fff647c33a14b31': {'amount': 3000, 'name': 'sriram sathyan'}, '5a27cf173f978655f2efbee7': {'amount': 1200, 'name': 'karthik subbaraj'}}
```

(What i wanted!!!!!)

So the question is =>
How could the placement of the if statement cause such a change? Or is it something that i am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the first case you are *overriding `names[report_id]`* on this line:

```
names[report_id] = {'name': item['_id'].get('name','')}
```

Let's follow the `5a27cda63fff647c33a14b31` item in the `names` dictionary:

1. On the first iteration of the loop, you are setting the value of `names[report_id]`:

   ```
   {'5a27cda63fff647c33a14b31': {'name': ''}}
   ```
2. Then, since the amount is 3000, the dictionary is updated to:

   ```
   {'5a27cda63fff647c33a14b31': {'name': '', 'amount': 3000}}
   ```
3. Then, on the second iteration of the loop, the dictionary is completely overridden leading to losing the `amount` value altogether:

   ```
   {'5a27cda63fff647c33a14b31': {'name': 'sriram sathyan'}}
   ```

Use the debugger to follow the execution line by line, watch how the `names` dictionary changes.

Comment: Thank you . I really appreciate the time taken to edit and format the answer this way :)

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that you have identical keys, one with `amount` equal to zero in the data, and one with `amount` *not* zero.

in the first loop, the entry with a non-zero `amount` is created first, then is overwritten by the entry with zero `amount`

So both codes overwrite some entries, but the first code overwrites the entries you want to keep, whereas the second one (the one that works) overwrite the entries with zero `amount`.